# Express.js - Multer File Filter Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I want to filter the files while uploading them to the server but the **Multer** `fileFilter` method is not working.

**Backend**

`destination` and `filename` methods are working as well, but `fileFilter` is not working.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./public/images/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
  fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
    console.log("Hello Word"); // This doesn't work either

    var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    if (!['.jpg', '.jpeg'].includes(ext)) {
      return callback(new Error('Only images are allowed'));
    }

    callback(null, true);
  },
});

app.use(
  multer({ storage: storage }).fields([
    { name: "logo", maxCount: 1 },
    { name: "favicon", maxCount: 1 },
  ])
);
```

**Frontend**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Logo</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="logo" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Favicon</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="favicon" accept="image/x-icon" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide all your code or a link to the repository ;-) What error is the console show?

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Comment: @MarioG8 Yes i solved, thank's a lot.

Comment: So you can mark my answer as solving your question ;-) Best regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filterMethod` works fine. This can be checked by changing the value in `input accept="image/*"` Then when we try to load a file other than `ico` or `jpg` we will get an error : `Only images are allowed`.
Your code needs some tweaking, additionaly i used the `ejs` [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs), here is my suggestion for a solution:

---

**Folder & File** project structure:

[image]

**app.js** - With Your `fileFilter` code.

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/views"));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./images");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log(req.file);

    cb(null, new Date().toUTCString() + " - " + file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
    console.log("Hello, World! Works fine;-)");

    var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    if (![".jpg", ".ico"].includes(ext)) {
      return callback(new Error("Only images are allowed"));
    }

    callback(null, true);
  },
});

app.post(
  "/post",
  upload.fields([
    { name: "logo", maxCount: 1 },
    { name: "favicon", maxCount: 1 },
  ]),
  (req, res, next) => {
    const files = req.files;
    if (!files) {
      const error = new Error("Please upload a file");
      error.httpStatusCode = 400;
      return next(error);
    }
    res.send(files);
    console.log("Success", req.files);
  }
);

app.get("/post", (req, res) => {
  res.render("post");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:3000/post`);
})
```

---

**post.ejs** - With Your *frontend* `form` code and my additional `input submit`:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Logo</td>
        <td>
          <input type="file" name="logo" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Favicon</td>
        <td>
          <input type="file" name="favicon" accept="image/x-icon" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

---

`http://localhost:3000/post` route output in browser:

[image]

---

**Output** after `submit` - `Upload File`. Files specified in `fields name` **logo** and **favicon**.

[image]

---

**Output** on `server side` and in `images` folder:

[image]

*Tested with: `node v16.13.0` "ejs": "^3.1.6","express": "^4.17.2","multer": "^1.4.4"*

Comment: I deleted some fields to make the code less visible. This worked when I added `upload.fields` to the route. Thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: You're Welcome !  Best regards ;-)